# Cron job not running since upgrading to Magento 2.2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, cron, crontab

In my old version of my site i had a cron that ran at 2am every morning to product some reports from my Module. I have it set up as normal with my class in the cron folder and the correct xml in crontab.xml but this is what the cron_schedule table is showing :

[image]

And i'm also getting this error in cron.log

> [2022-08-04 19:08:08] main.ERROR: Cron Job reinitpricing_cronjob has
> an error: Too few arguments to function
> Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Indexer\LinkedProductSelectBuilderByIndexPrice::build(),
> 1 passed in
> /domains/XX.XX.co.uk/http/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php
> on line 58 and exactly 2 expected. Statistics:
> {"sum":0,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":0,"realmem_start":106954752,"emalloc_start":42932736}
> [] [] [

Does anyone know how i can resolve this?

Comment: I think u need to check if u are passing the correct number of parameters (arguments) to the function. U are passing to few arguments. I.e. function expects 3 arguments but u are passing only 2. please share the corresponding code.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue.
Have you checked that cron is installed on your magento. If not install it.

Comment: Try on Ubuntu: systemctl status cron

Comment: Its not in my list when i do crontab -l but you can see it is running because i can see it in the table. What should i do to install it?

Comment: use this command bin/magento cron:install

Comment: Since it does a lot of looping i thought it might be the admin session timeout so i tried to change it but it says The "system/security/max_session_size_admin" path doesn't exist. Verify and try again. And when i look in the back end i dont have a security tab in advanced :/ ive noticed this before when looking for 2fa

Comment: oh yes i have installed it already. Its running i believe but throwing the error above

Comment: it says Crontab has already been generated and saved.

Comment: You can got to the admin panel check the cron list and refresh it

Comment: The cron is running its throwing the error above

Comment: You can use this : bin/magento config:set system/security/max_session_size_admin 0

Comment: If this resolve your issue then mark this as an answer